# Envy somebody something

Tags: prepositions, verbs, personal-pronouns

In *Advanced Grammar in Use (Cambridge)* the following sentence is grammatically correct

> We all envied him his lifestyle.

Is the meaning of the particular sentence the same as the sentence

> We all envied him **for** his lifestyle. ?

Comment: Yes, it's his private jets, exclusive vacations, expensive clothes, fine dining, fast cars, choice of wines, size of house, limitless credit card, massive art collection, beautiful friends, etc. that you **envy**.  It's **because of** or **for** his lifestyle.

Comment: @Peter That should be an answer, because it really helped me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's his

> private jets
>   exclusive vacations
>   expensive clothes
>   fine dining
>   fast cars
>   choice of wines
>   size of house
>   limitless credit cards
>   massive art collection
>   beautiful friends
>   etc.

that you **envy**.

All those things (and possibly more) are the **accoutrements** of his **lifestyle**.
You envy him **for** those things.
You envy him **for** his lifestyle.

Alternatively, you could **envy** him **for** his **good looks** or his **sense of humour**
but those are not part of his lifestyle

Comment: So "I envy him his lifestyle" means "I envy his lifestyle" ?

Comment: "I envy him **for** his lifestyle is correct. If you use "I envy him his lifestyle" the Grammar Gestapo will lock you up(!) you need to add **for**

Comment: This is mentioned in http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/envy_2 : envy somebody something,  **I envied him his good looks**.

Comment: I've only heard "I envied him for his good looks" or "I envied his good looks", possibly its a BrE way of using envy, they drop words (from an AmE perspective) from time to time. I think if you said it to an AmE speaker they would think you said "I envied him: his good looks, his fast cars, his big house."

Comment: I can't agree with this: *envy* can be monotransitive, taking as object either the person or the possession, or ditransitive, taking both as objects.

Comment: @StoneyB So, "I envied his lifestyle", "I envied the fast cars", "I envied his lifestyle and the fast cars","I envied his lifestyle the fast cars" are all correct?

Comment: @Peter My gut feel is that the possessor has to be expressed, but not necessarily as an object, e.g. "I envied the fast cars he drove", "I envied the lifestyle he enjoyed" -- or, as you expressed it, as a possessive, "I envied his lifestyle*, just as the possession may be expressed otherwise than as an object with *for*.

Answer (score 2):

The verb construction is to envy someone something. Oald gives a survey about the possible constructions. The construction with "for" is not listed.
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/envy_2

In AmE the construction with for is used:
I envy you for your large group of friends.
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/envy